# Recognization of module is placed on local site or live site

Tags: dotnetnuke

When site is running on local machine DNN allows me to edit and update source of my custom modules. But, when it is hosted on server and accessing via live URL it does not allow me to edit source.

From where DNN recognized that this site is running on local machine or live for my custom module' option Develop?

This is only for my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are logged in with the Host/SuperUser account on both sites?

I am able to get to the Develop option when I am in Edit mode for my modules on my production site without any problems, but I am logged in with the HOST account.

Comment: I logged in with host account on both my local and production site. I am not able to edit module on production site though I am getting an option for develop.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't installed a compiled version of the module in Production?

Comment: I installed module via Host>Extensions>Create New Module
Same thing allows me to edit module on local machine.